# Getting Access Denied for folder as Administrator

Tags: security, windows-server-2012-r2, directory

On a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, logged in as domain administrator trying to access the c:\users\public\desktop folder, getting access denied.  This machine is the domain controller.

How can I get access to this folder?

1. Using takeown from cmd.exe using runas as the local domain administrator:

> ```
> C:\Users\Public>takeown /f c:\users\public\desktop
> ERROR: Access is denied.
> ```

2. Tried icacls

> ```
> C:\Users\Public>icacls Desktop /t /grant Everyone:F
> Desktop: Access is denied.
> Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
> ```

3. Viewing it via explorer when logged in as domain administrator

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is UAC enabled? Try turning it off if it is.